# Where does Captain America live?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, captain-america

In the Age of Ultron, someone asks Captain America if he has found a place in Brooklyn yet.  And Captain America replies that he does not think he can afford a place in Brooklyn.

So where does Captain America live?

I am asking specifically about where he lives in the general time frame of *Age of Ultron*.  However, if you can answer this specific time frame question, then elaborating on where he lived in other time frames would also be interesting.

I seem to recall him going to Los Angeles in the 1980s Captain America movie.  And he was also obviously in Europe.  He seems to be staying with the group in *Age of Ultron*, and then he seems to move to upstate New York at the end of Ultron to train new Avengers.  But where was he living right before the start of *Age of Ultron*?

Comment: Same apt as in winter soldier?

Comment: I would assume he lives in the Avenger's tower.

Comment: America, one would hope.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Current residence: unknown.

However, during *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, he appears to be living in Washington DC or the surrounding area, where the bulk of the movie takes place.

Specifically, his apartment (where Nick Fury visits) visually appears to be in the Adams Morgan area (considering the architecture and skyline). Arlington would be another likely area for him to live (*sliiiiightly* closer to The Mall, where we see him exercising at the beginning, as well as closer to the Triskellion).

His apartment is damaged during the film, though, and he may have been required to find a new one.

Comment: Looked more like Georgetown to me, which would be closer commute to the Triskelion as well.

Answer (score 2):

Captain America lives in an apartment next to Agent 13, a shield agent assigned to protect him. The apartment was listed as being located in the Bronx from New Avengers #48-#51 but was corrected in New Avengers #52. It had previously been listed as being located in Brooklyn for several episodes of Captain America Vol 5.

Answer (score 0):

In the Avengers they probably have bedrooms so captain America stays in Avengers Tower at the beginning of Acvengers: Age of Ultron

Answer (score -1):

I think Brooklyn because in captain America civil war Spider-Man says he lives in queens the Steve says he lives in Brooklyn. So which Brooklyn? NY or Boston

Comment: there is no Brooklyn Ma. There's a BrookLINE :D